# How to call WCF REST-Service with URI parameter

Tags: javascript, wcf, rest, uri

I have a WCF Rest-Service with a method that expects string parameter. This parameter is a Uri. To be able to use an URI as a parameter for the REST Service, I used the JavaScript method **encodeURIComponent** to encode the URI

```
http://creativeartefact.org/example/fa9eb3e7-8297-4541-81ec-e9e9be6e6638
```

becomes

```
http%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2Fexample%2Ffa9eb3e7-8297-4541-81ec-e9e9be6e6638
```

When I call the service with a normal String, everything is fine

```
../liveEvents/qwertz
```

When I call it with the encoded Uri (I entered the request directly in my browser) , I get a "no endpoint found" error.

```
../liveEvents/http%3A%2F%2Fcreativeartefact.org%2Fexample%2Ffa9eb3e7-8297-4541-81ec-e9e9be6e6638
```

Any idea what might be the problem and how to safely pass a URI as a parameter to a WCF REST Service with JavaScript?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Edit: Here is the Endpoint Method:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "liveEvents/{artistUri}")]
IList<LiveEvent> GetLiveEventsList(string artistUri);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't use UriTemplates. WCF also works without them and they don't make a difference (as far as I see) when calling from JavaScript.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
IList<LiveEvent> GetLiveEventsList(string artistUri);
```

Call the service like this:

```
http://theserver.com/Service.svc/GetLiveEventsList?artistUri=http://creativeartefact.org/example/fa9eb3e7-8297-4541-81ec-e9e9be6e6638
```

Additional, no need for encoding here.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the url as query string parameter.
Suppose your Get method signature is like this:

```
Get(string id)
```

The you just call with this url:

```
'/liveEvents/?id=' + encodeURIComponent('http://test.com/?name=Foo&id=2')
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I added the method signature in the question. Using the ?artistUri= did not help. Even the test request with /?artistUri=qwertz now fails with the "no endpoint found" error.

Comment: So, based in your question, your your GetLiveEventsList method response for Get verb.
Can you call the method opening in browser using http://yourdns/liveEvents/?artistUri=qwertz  ? Does it work?